# Função JAVASCRIPT dentro do DO WHILE

Tags: php, javascript

No DO WHILE abaixo ele exibe 4 dados do banco, quando eu clico em um dos botões com a função mostrar() aparece somemente a primeira linha, mesmo quando eu clico em qualquer outro botão sempre me mostra o primeiro dado. O que devo fazer pra corrigir?.

```
<?php require_once('Connections/conexao.php');

mysql_select_db($database_conexao, $conexao);
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM produtos";
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $conexao) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style_pdv.css" />
<title>Documento sem título</title>
<script>
function mostrar(){
    var t1 = document.getElementById('tx1').value; //Pega o value do input tx1
    var t2 = document.getElementById('tx2').value; //Pega o value do input tx2
    var t3 = document.getElementById('tx3').value; //Pega o value do input tx3
    document.getElementById('v1').value=t1; //Joga o value do input tx1 no input v1
    document.getElementById('v2').value=t2; //Joga o value do input tx2 no input v1
    document.getElementById('v3').value=t3; //Joga o value do input tx3 no input v1
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<?php do { ?>
<input name="tx1" id="tx1" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['nome']; ?>" />
<input name="tx2" id="tx2" type="text" value="1" />
<input name="tx3" id="tx3" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['preco']; ?>" />
<input name="btn" id="btn" type="button" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['nome']; ?>" onclick="mostrar()" /><br />
<?php } while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)); ?>

<br /><br />
Produto: <input name="v1" id="v1" type="text" value="" />
Quantidade: <input name="v2" id="v2" type="text" value="" />
Preço: <input name="v3" id="v3" type="text" value="" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Da forma como está, a comunidade teria que adivinhar o que você quer fazer e estudar seu código para tentar começar a entender seu problema. Queira reduzir seu código a um [Mcve] e descrever minuciosamente a dificuldade para eventualmente viabilizar o post. Uma lida em [Ask] e [Help] talvez ajude.

Comment: **Nota:** O comentário do @Bacco está correto e tem muito valor para ti como novo membro da comunidade. Vou arriscar ter percebido a tua pergunta e colocar uma resposta. Comenta por favor se a resposta vai de encontro ao que procuras.

Comment: @LipESprY o fato de você ter entendido não faz com que ela fique adequada ao site e aqui não é um helpdesk (que aliás é uma das coisas que no meu ver torna o site uma bagunça), mas já que o Sergio que também é moderador entendeu de forma diferente, me abstenho de novas ações nesse caso específico. A pergunta só serve ao próprio autor, as respostas podem não ser suficientes e nesses casos se quer ajudar o autor (o que eu acho louvável), basta por num pastebin e linkar nos comments, assim resolve o problema dele sem efeitos colaterais (eu mesmo já fiz isso muitas vezes aqui).

Comment: @LipESprY muitas vezes o melhor é realmente o autor editar e deixar mais claros os problemas, assim a gente ajuda ele e ajuda os futuros visitantes. Os fechamentos não são "punição", e tirando o "realmente fora de escopo" o usuário é convidado sempre a melhorar e elaborar o post, pois assim temos a melhor situação possível: ajudar o autor e deixar um legado. Não precisa ser a ferro e fogo, dá para chegar num bom equilíbrio (normalmente as orientações são sempre no sentido de melhorar para reabrir).

Comment: O que eu vi de interessante nesta pergunta, e daí a resposta, é o erro comum de gerar IDs duplicadas e não perceber os error que vêm daí. Gerar HTML via PHP é um caso comum e uma solução sem IDs parece-me interessante de partilhar.

Comment: @LipESprY em nenhum momento duvidei de vc ter entendido, pq nao é esse o ponto. O ponto é "qualquer um, com um minimo de noção da coisa entender", pq o futuro visitante vai estar navegando por um monte de post para procurar alguma ajuda, ficaria inviável ele analisar código por código pra ver se aquilo serve. A solução pode ser simples, mas se a pergunta precisa de análise para um usuário saber se é o mesmo caso dele, perdeu o valor como repositório de conhecimento. Normalmente não são Sergios e LipESprYs que vão estar procurando ajuda, mas pessoas com menos poder de análise e tempo sobrando.

Comment: Se a solução é o que o @Sergio disse (resolver os IDs), tenho a impressão de que é duplicata, mas realmente acho que não tenho muito a acrescentar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estás a criar elementos todos com a mesma ID. IDs têm de ser únicas em HTML, por isso tens de adicionar lógica que incremente essas IDs (para serem únicas)  ou lógica que não precise de IDs!

Sugiro a ultima abordagem. Para isso é útil ter uma `<div>` à volta desses inputs, e passar o `this` no `onclick="mostrar()"` para saber o ponto de partida...

Um exemplo seria assim:

```js
function mostrar(btn) {
  const div = btn.closest('div');
  var t1 = div.querySelector('[name="tx1"]').value;
  var t2 = div.querySelector('[name="tx2"]').value;
  var t3 = div.querySelector('[name="tx3"]').value;
  document.getElementById('v1').value = t1;
  document.getElementById('v2').value = t2;
  document.getElementById('v3').value = t3;
}
```

```html
</script>
</head>

<body>

  <?php do { ?>
  <div>
    <input name="tx1" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['nome']; ?>" />
    <input name="tx2" type="text" value="1" />
    <input name="tx3" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['preco']; ?>" />
    <input name="btn" type="button" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['nome']; ?>" onclick="mostrar(this)" /><br />
  </div>
  <?php } while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)); ?>

  <br /><br /> Produto: <input name="v1" id="v1" type="text" value="" /> Quantidade: <input name="v2" id="v2" type="text" value="" /> Preço: <input name="v3" id="v3" type="text" value="" />
```

Comment: Não conhecia o método `.closest()`. Ótima solução! +1